# Is this observer going to work?

Tags: magento-1.9

I just completed this observer, and i want your opinion if this going to work, the order status will based on the ordered product sku.

What i'm trying to achieve is, if the ordered product has sku ends with "FBA", then assign certain status, if not just go normal.

So i defined the state to be used, and calling the skus from the orders, and checking from that in order to check from it.

But yet it's not working for some reason.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

```
public function changestatus($event) {

$_order = $event->getOrder();

$STATE = 'amazonfba';

foreach($orders as $order){
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku();
    }
}
if(strpos($sku, '_FBA') === true){
    $_order->addStatusHistoryComment('Amazon FBA', $STATE)
                   ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                   ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
}
    return $this;
}
}
```

EDIT:

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_FBA>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_FBA>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <company_fba>
                <class>Company_FBA_Model</class>
            </company_fba>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <company_fba>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>company_fba/observer</class>
                        <method>changestatus</method>
                    </company_fba>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: You can explain more about the purpose of this observer?

Comment: Well, simply if condition met, assign the orderstatus.

Comment: Which event observer you tried to catch? Please add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That if condition only checks if the last item in the last order does not contain _FBA string or the sku starts with _FBA (strpos returns the position of the searched string in haystack, 0 indexed). So you should check for false value like this `strpos(...) === false`.

I suggest you to concatenate all sku values into a string ( like `$sku .= $item->getSku()`, initialize $sku variable before first foreach ) or creats an array of sku's and check with in_array function.

As a side note, you should tell us what are you trying to achieve and what observer do you use for that purpose

Comment: Updated the original post, please read it.

Comment: You are placing the event in the adminhtml area, so the observer won't trigger when placing the order in frontend, so place events tag under global tag. $orders variable isn't initialized. Remove the first foreach and pay attention to variable naming. You should use `$_order->getAllVisibleItems()`.

Comment: Also, you are looping through all order items but check for the last product's sku. I would suggest you to move if statement inside foreach. The condition should be `if( substr($sku,-4) == '_FBA') { ..additional code here; break;  }` break is used to break out of for since we found a matching product.

Comment: At last, you should save the $_order variable after you change it's properties: `$_order->addStatus.......->save();`

Comment: public function changestatus($event) {

$_order = $event->getOrder();
$STATE = 'amazonfba';
$items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems()
foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku()
    }
 
if( substr($sku,-4) == '_FBA'){
    $_order->addStatusHistoryComment('Amazon FBA', $STATE)
                   ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                   ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
       ->save();
       
break;
}
   Mage::log('testing');
}
}

Comment: Also, make sure you enable your module in app/etc/modules/Company_FBA.xml

Comment: I have done enabled that for sure.

Comment: But the question is, does it look as you suggested? going to test it now.

Comment: You are adding a } after $sku = $item->getSku(). Remove it so that if statement is inside foreach. Also, pay attention to semicolons

Comment: You confused me about the $sku, it's inside foreach already, can you take a look at the code i commented?

Comment: public function changestatus($event) {

$_order = $event->getOrder();
$STATE = 'amazonfba';
$items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku();
    }
 
if( substr($sku,-4) == '_FBA'){
    $_order->addStatusHistoryComment('Amazon FBA', $STATE)
                   ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                   ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
       ->save();
       
break;
}
   Mage::log('testing');
}
}

Comment: Show me your version plz

Comment: public function changestatus($event) {  $_order = $event->getOrder(); $STATE = 'amazonfba'; $items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();  foreach($items as $item){         $sku = $item->getSku();        if( substr($sku,-4) == '_FBA'){     $_order->addStatusHistoryComment('Amazon FBA', $STATE)                    ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)                    ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)        ->save();         break; }    Mage::log('testing'); } }

Comment: The only thing which needed to be removed was the } after $item->getSku();. Also, update the module xml and place the events tag under global tag. Why aren't you just test it? Is it a live system and you cannot make any orders or what is happening?

Comment: This worked, but odd i see this http://prntscr.com/cdl0d9... it should end up with the status i assigned, but yet it's ending with pending which i don't want !!

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?> <config> ............    <global>        <events>             <sales_order_place_after><!-- observe the event -->                 <observers>                     <company_fba>                         <type>singleton</type>                         <class>company_fba/observer</class>                         <method>changestatus</method>                     </company_fba>                 </observers>             </sales_order_place_after>         </events>    </global>     </config>`

Comment: No worries, it worked great, i just adjusted the config xml :)

Comment: I did that :) do you have skype?

Comment: I do ;) but in this mobile app I cannot find how to send a private message

Comment: So if you find it, send me a message and I will send you my skype id

Comment: Just put yours and delete it in 1 min.

Comment: I'll search for that button when I'll be on PC and I'll send it to you

Comment: That button seems to be removed. Let me you skype and i'll add you

Comment: @JAMES ? Can i delete it?

Comment: Yes please, just delete it when you can, i just emailed you my skype.